# Need example of a web form editing a parent entity object with children

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, poco

I'm working on an "edit" page for an object.  On this page, I would like to have something like a DetailsView allowing editing of properties of the object as well as a GridView with children and allowing for simple Add/Edit/Delete of the children.  The updates to the parent or child objects shouldn't save to the database until a Save button is clicked.  I'm asp.net web forms and Entity Framework

As a simple example, imagine a Project object with a collection of Resources.  I am building a page that allows a user to change Project properties such as ProjectName in a DetailsView as well as add/edit/deleting a Resource in a Gridview below.  One Save button at the bottom saves everything.

I've found examples of this in MVC, but am having trouble finding a web forms example.

Comment: I do not have made this schema, but an idea is to save the children changed data on viewstate until the master data go for save, then save them all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to code your application for you but I have accomplished this using one of two variants of the same pattern.

Create a record object for your children that is serializable and maintain that in a ViewState based List. If the data is significantly large, consider maintaining it in Session and use a unique key to your Session object (such as a GUID assigned at Page_Load) and stored the key in ViewState.

When your use is done editing the parent / children, you will have to resolve the changed to your ViewState / Session based objects to those stored on disk.

Comment: I was able to get this working using ViewState as you suggested to store my entity objects.  The biggest challenge was that I was attempting to use an EntityDataSource for the Gridview and DetailsView. This didn't work and I ended up using the direct entity object as the datasource and coding the value assignments in the Updating events.

Comment: Correct, none of the standard data sources will work when disconnected from your database. Watch your viewstate size. If it starts to become an issue, consider moving your temp data store to session with a veiwstate based key.